# Maximum Monthly Values whilst retaining the Data at which that values occured

Tags: python, pandas, max, weather

I have daily rainfall data that looks like the following:

Date            Rainfall (mm) 
1922-01-01   0.0 
1922-01-02     0.0 
1922-01-03   0.0
1922-01-04   0.0
1922-01-05  31.5
1922-01-06     0.0
1922-01-07     0.0
1922-01-08   0.0
1922-01-09     0.0
1922-01-10     0.0
1922-01-11     0.0
1922-01-12     9.1
1922-01-13     6.4 
.
.
.

I am trying to work out the maximum value for each month for each year, and also what date the maximum value occurred on. I have been using the code:

```
rain_data.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq = 'M'))['Rainfall (mm)'].max()
```

This is returning the correct maximum value but returns the end date of each month rather than the date that maximum event occurred on.

1974-11-30      0.0
 1974-12-31      0.0
 1975-01-31     0.0
 1975-02-28    65.0
 1975-03-31   129.5
 1975-11-30    59.9
 1975-12-31     7.1
 1976-01-31    10.0
 1976-11-30     0.0
 1976-12-31     0.0
 1977-01-31     4.3

Any suggestions on how I could get the correct date?

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to this, but what I think you're doing in `(pd.Grouper(freq = 'M'))` is grouping all the values in each month, but it's assigning every value within a group to the same date. I think this is why your `groupby` isn't returning the dates you're looking for.

I think your question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35754638/getting-the-monthly-maximum-of-a-daily-dataframe-with-the-corresponding-index-va). [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2411802/alexander) suggests to use:

`df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('M')).Close.agg({'max date': 'idxmax', 'max rainfall': np.max})`

The `agg` works without the `Close` I think, so if it's problematic (as I found) you might want to take it out.