# Getting the monthly daily maximum with a grouped dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a similar question to this: [Getting the monthly maximum of a daily dataframe with the corresponding index value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35754638/getting-the-monthly-maximum-of-a-daily-dataframe-with-the-corresponding-index-va) but cannot install `from pandas.io.data import DataReader`. My original dataframe is:

```
df
Datum      ID Value
01.01.2020   1  2
02.01.2020   1  1
01.02.2020   1  3
01.01.2020   2  2
01.02.2020   2  0
```

And i groupby the Dates to get the total value per everydate:

```
df.groupby('Datum')['Value'].sum().reset_index()
Datum       Value
01.01.2020   4
02.01.2020   2
01.02.2020   2
```

How can I pick the maximum per month in that case? I mean the 01.01.2020 and 01.02.2020.

so the output should be:

```
Datum       Value
01.01.2020   4
01.02.2020   2
```

or a list with the dates: `alist = ['01.01.2020', '01.02.2020']`

Comment: Can you add expected output DataFrame?

Comment: output is added

Comment: Please check dupe, if still not working let me know.

Comment: already solved, this is was searching for, thx